# Ruby On Rails Dynamic Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a list of 1000+ cities,  I would like to generate routes for each city, e.g:

```
www.example.com/NewYork-Cinemas
www.example.com/Boston-Cinemas
```

would redirect to:

```
www.example.com/city_id=1234
www.example.com/city_id=1235
```

How can I add these types of routes to the routes.rb file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to consider two important factors:

> 1. Your routes should be `resourceful`
> 2. Using "slugs" in your routes is the role of third-party extensions

Here's how to acheive what you want:

---

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :cities, path: "", only: :show #-> domain.com/:id

#app/controllers/cities_controller.rb
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @city = City.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

The above routes might not be what you wanted, but they'll do something very important - they'll give you a resourceful structure (which maintains the convention of Rails):

[image]

I like posting this picture a lot - most people don't know it exists. [You can find it here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) -- it explains how you should keep your routes *resourceful*. Other answers just recommended creating a new custom route - bad news. You need to keep your routes structured as possible, otherwise they become unwieldy

---

**Find**

Secondly, you'll want to heed the recommendation of another answer, and employ the use of [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) in your app:

```
#app/models/city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the "slug" name in your title. Friendly ID will automatically take care of the entire process - you can [watch a Railscast about it here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to generate slug for each city, and then you could define in your `routes.rb` like this

```
get '/:city_slug' => 'cities#show'
```

In your controllers

```
def cities_controller
   def show
      @city = City.friendly.find(params[:city_slug])
   end
end
```

Hope you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

In your city model:

```
def to_param
  city_name
end
```

The to_param method on ActiveRecord objects uses, by default, just the ID of the object. By putting this code in your model, you're overwriting the ActiveRecord default, so when you link to a City, it will use the city name for the parameter instead of id.

OR

In routes file

**resources :city, param: :cityname**

Comment: The problem with this is, that everything breaks if cities is renamed or two cities have the same name (yes, this happens). The friendly_id gem is the solution to overcome this.